# Can't skip "publish_permission", always asks for it

Tags: facebook, permissions

It's an optional permission, but I cannot skip it in my canvas app, when I click "skip" on this permission my page are redirected to ask this permission again and again and again. Anyone have an idea of why is this happening?

Many thanks! :)

```
<!-- BEGINNING OF THE INDEX.PHP CODE -->
<?php

  //SOLVES INFINITE LOOP ON IE
  header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

  // Enforce https on production
  if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
    header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(  'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),  'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(), ));

  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  //Check if we have an user_id
  if ($user_id!="0") {

        try {
          // Fetch the viewer's basic information
          $basic = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          // If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
          // cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
          if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
            header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
            exit();
          }
        }

  } else { 

    // If the user is not connected to the application, redirect the user to authentication page 
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => "https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME_SPACE/",'scope' =>  'publish_stream,email','display' => 'page')); 

    ?><html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
       <script type="text/javascript"> top.location.href='<?php echo $login_url; ?>'</script> 
      </body>
      </html><?php   

        exit();
  }

  if(isset($basic)) {

    $locale=idx($basic, 'locale');
    $name=he(idx($basic, 'name'));
    $email=he(idx($basic, 'email'));

  } else {

    // IF the user is not loggin on facebook, redirect the user to facebook login page
    ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
    oauth_url += '?client_id=APP_ID';
     oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME_SPACE/');
     oauth_url += '&scope=publish_stream,email'
     window.top.location = oauth_url;
    </script>
<?php
    exit();
    //ends execution if there's no login
  }


  ?>
<html>
 // APP HTML CODE
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your auth code it's hard to be sure, but i'd be confident that you have

- A check to see what permissions were granted and are redirecting back to the dialog if some are missing, or
- A call to `FB.login()` with certain permissions specified in the JS SDK, something like that

both will result in a loop if you don't account for users skipping the requests

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Igy! I believe that it's none of that possibilities. Can you take a look at my code? I've edit it on my original post. Besides, it's worth of noticing that in my canvas page definitions i've defined Authenticated Referrals, with "User & Friend Permissions" to email and "Extended Permissions" with publish_stream.

Answer (score 0):

he's using the facebook sdk library, evidently. I've never heard of skipping permissions. You set them in the appropriate function when it is time to build the URL for authentication. It would be worth retrieving the login authentication flow, but try `oauth_url += '&scope=email'` instead of what you have? Alternatively you can try to build the oauth url without scopes and see what permissions the application asks. If it asks for specific permissions, check the login function and see if there are some permissions already set. It should be, if I remember correctly, in the facebook.php file.